# cakephp $uses plugin section

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am learning cakephp and I have this code that is appearently in a plugin folder in a folder called testifying and under the testifying plugin, in the controllers there is a file called dispatch_controller.php

When I opened the dispatch_controller.php I have this

```
var $uses = array('TestifyinItem', 'Customer','Audio','User','Testifying.Profile','Analytics.Statistic','Cron.CronJob');
```

Now I couldnt find TestifyinItem in that folder but when I went to app/models I found Testifying_item.php.
I couldnt find CronJob in any folder but there is a folder in plugins named cron_job  and has a class called CronJob in it.... 
I think I am confused as to where to find what and how.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out Cake's naming conventions on this page:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/509/Coding-Standards#Variables-609

You will see that file names should be in lower case, with words separated by underscores; while class names should be written in CamelCase.

Hopefully this will help you understand how cron_job and CronJob are related.  I agree that Cake's conventions take a little getting used to at first, though...